# My pregnant wife with Green card status is stuck in India due to COVID-19, What are my options as she cannot come until she gives birth?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, us-permanent-residents

My wife is stuck in India since Feb 24, she's supposed to come on April 30th. But, all flights were cancelled including ours. There are repatriation flights, but, she is 32.5 weeks pregnant when the repatriation flights start running from India to U.S during next phase.

I am thinking my wife will come back to U.S before August 18th (she'll be outside for 177 days) after she gives birth at the end of July.

Can she go back to India after 2 months of staying in U.S to take care of our baby? (Meantime, my parents will be taking care of the baby). Will she face any more questions?

(I am a U.S. citizen and not worried about my kid as I can apply for CRBA)

Please be nice as we are going through a tough time staying apart like so many others.

EDITED for clarity:

1. Will she face any more questions when she comes back to U.S for the second time?
2. Does the 180 days stay outside U.S. for LPR applies for the calendar year or only for continuous stay outside U.S? Meaning, can a person with LPR go outside stay for 5 1/2 months, stay in U.S. for a month and go outside U.S. and stay for 5 1/2 more months?

Comment: Can't be cited as a duplicate as it has no accepted answer, but this question, comments, and answers may be of use to you: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157217/child-born-outside-usa-to-green-card-parents?r=SearchResults&s=3|42.8246

Comment: Will she face any more questions from whom?  And nobody's going to stop her from going to India, assuming she's an Indian citizen and that there are no public health measures preventing her travel.  Why do you wonder whether it will be possible?

Comment: I was wondering if she is going to face questions when comes back (to U.S.) second time with a possible questioning of "spending most of the year outside U.S." I was mostly wondering if 180 days condition of staying outside U.S. applies to continuous stay or not

Comment: There are flights from India to US currently running operated by Air India. They are originally meant to go to US (among other countries) to bring back indians stranded there, but during the onward journey they are taking passengers who are willing to travel to US or other countries. Here is the schedule 
http://www.airindia.in/images/pdf/Web-schedule-phase-2-complete-24-May-20-0100-Hrs-converted.pdf

You can book these flights on Air India website

Comment: Gynecologist recommended against traveling at this point in pregnancy

Comment: Why would she spend almost a year in India, rather than one of you bringing the child back to the US as soon as you can get the paperwork done?

Comment: Yes, we will bring as soon as I will get the paperwork done. I wanted to check the 180 day rule of staying abroad for LPR

Comment: @would_like_to_be_anon questions about the 180-day rule belong on [Expatriates.SE].  But in short, she can even stay away from the US for 11 1/2 months or longer than a year.  She will not automatically lose her permanent residence in any case, but the chance that the US will begin proceedings to take it away from her increases the longer she's away.  In these circumstances the chance seems very small in any case.

Comment: I think the real situation, staying only as long as is forced by COVID travel issues, medical advice, and getting paperwork for the newborn, is unlikely to cause issues. The hypothetical of spending 11 months in India, split by one month in the US, looks more like someone who lives in India and visits the US than the other way round, and could cause problems. Whether one's actions show intent to abandon US resident status seems to be more important than the 180 day rule.